# Posting form data using request module - Nodejs & Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using a platform for data security, and they have this code snippet showing how to post data to their platform:

They're using the request module: https://github.com/mikeal/request

```
const request = require('request');

request({
    url: 'https://mypass.testproxy.com/post',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    body: JSON.stringify({'secret' : 'secret_value'})
  }, function(error, response, body){
    if(error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      console.log('Status:', response.statusCode);
      console.log(JSON.parse(body));
    }
});
```

It works fine, but I wanted to replace the 'secret' : 'secret_value' object with my form data, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do this.
The only way I know how to retrieve form data is with req.body:

```
function(req, res) {
var form = {
  card_number: req.body.card_number,
  card_cvv: req.body.cvv,
  card_expirationDate: req.body.card_expirationDate,
};
    // ...
});
```

How would I do that? Any help is greatly appreciated.

I know the code below is wrong, but that's the idea of what I want to achieve:

````
request( function(req, res) {
var form = {
  card_number: req.body.card_number,
  card_cvv: req.body.cvv,
  card_expirationDate: req.body.card_expirationDate,
};{
    url: 'https://mypass.testproxy.com/post',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    body: JSON.stringify(form)
...```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form data will be sent with the content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` e.g. `card_number=123&cvv=456`.

Express has a middleware to parse that https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.urlencoded

```
app.use(express.urlencoded());
```

The parsed values will be in `req.body` in your post route. So e.g. `req.body.card_number` will contain the value `123`.

You can put the request inside the route:

```
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
  var form = { /* ... */ }
  request({
    body: JSON.stringify(form),
    /* ... */
  })
})
```